# Use matrix[0].length to present the row's length of an empty 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

for example: 2D empty array: `[]`

Can I use `matrix[0].length` here?

It seems this will cause an IndexOutofBoundException. Can anyone explain to me why?

Comment: What runtime error do you get?

Comment: what is `matrix`? and you define a 2d array using two square braces `[][]` not `[]` , e.g. ... `int[][] a = new int[1][1];`

Comment: If it's empty, it has no rows, and thus its rows have no length.

Answer (score 3):

A 2D array can be measured like this:

```
int a[][];
int d1 = a.length;
int d2 = d1 > 0 ? a[0].length: 0;
```

Note that you **cannot** use `a[0]` if `a.length == 0`.

Please remember that just because `a[0].length == n` does not necessarily mean `a[1].length == n` because in Java each array element can have any length.